# Cannot list Azure Storage Gen 2 files with Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I wonder if my databricks code is addressing the correct location and if "contributor" right is enough for accessing storage.

1. I have Azure Storage Gen 2 with container named staging. (Url in Azure portal is https://datalaketest123.blob.core.windows.net/staging)
2. I have mounted Azure Storage Gen 2 with Azure Databricks.
3. I have configured passthrough and assuming that I get access to storage with my AD users. (contributor rights)
4. i have variable: source = 'abfss://' + in_fileSystemName + '@' + storageAccountName + '.dfs.core.windows.net/'
5. I tried now to list file system with command: dbutils.fs.ls(source)

I get error:

```
ET https://datalaketest123.dfs.core.windows.net/staging? 
resource=filesystem&amp;maxResults=500&amp;timeout=90&amp;recursive=false
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecutionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1012822525241408> in <module>
 27 # COMMAND ----------
 28 source = 'abfss://' + in_fileSystemName + '@' + storageAccountName + '.dfs.core.windows.net/'
---> 29 dbutils.fs.ls(source)
 30 
 31 # COMMAND ----------

/local_disk0/tmp/1235891082005-0/dbutils.py in f_with_exception_handling(*args, **kwargs)
    312                     exc.__context__ = None
    313                     exc.__cause__ = None
--> 314                     raise exc
    315             return f_with_exception_handling
    316 

ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling z:com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils.ls.
: GET https://datalaketest123.dfs.core.windows.net/staging? 
resource=filesystem&maxResults=500&timeout=90&recursive=false
StatusCode=403
StatusDescription=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
ErrorCode=AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [official Databricks docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2#create-and-grant-permissions-to-service-principal) only `Contributor` is not enough - it should be `Storage Blob Data XXX` (where XXX is `Owner`, `Contributor`, `Reader`, .... - [see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#azure-roles-for-blobs-and-queues))

Answer (score 1):

> When performing the steps in the Assign the application to a role, make sure that your user account has the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role assigned to it.

**Repro:** I have provided owner permission to the service principal and tried to run the “`dbutils.fs.ls("mnt/azure/")`”, returned same error message as above.

[image]

**Solution:** Now assigned the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to the service principal.

[image]

Finally, able to get the output without any error message after assigning the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the service principal.

[image]

**Reference:**  “[Tutorial: Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, Azure Databricks & Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-use-databricks-spark)”.